# No implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer error when import image from csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

When import a csv file I'm getting error: "No implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer". Error occurs when I add import photos.

advert model

```
require 'csv'
require 'open-uri'

class Advert < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy

private
    def self.import(file)
      CSV.foreach(file.path, col_sep: '||') do |row|
        Advert.create!( :title              => row[0],
                        :content            => row[1],
                        :photos_attributes  => {
                            :image => row[2],
                        }
                      )
      end
    end
end
```

photo model

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :advert

  validates :image, presence: true

  validates_associated :advert

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

end
```

in advert controller

```
def advert_params
  params.require(:advert).permit(
    :title,
    :content,
    photos_attributes: [:id, :advert_id, :image_cache, :image, :_destroy]
  )
end
```

csv

```
my title 1||my content 1||https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png
my title 2||my content 2||
my title 3||my content 3||https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png
my title 4||my content 4||
my title 5||my content 5||https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png
```

Trace

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer): app/models/advert.rb:299:in block in import' app/models/advert.rb:298:in import' app/controllers/admin/adverts_controller.rb:39:in import'
```

**UPD.** Remove header from csv.

Comment: Stack trace please. Would also help to remove headers from code and data per your comment to my answer.

Comment: Model is actually more complicated than in the example. So the line numbers in the log they use different numbers in the model.
Trace:
`TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):
  app/models/advert.rb:299:in `block in import'
  app/models/advert.rb:298:in `import'
  app/controllers/admin/adverts_controller.rb:39:in `import'`

Comment: Would be best to edit your question to include that error. Hard to read in the comment.

Comment: You're right. I added trace to the question.